# How do I know the variable names in a ros service handler

Tags: ros, rospy, rosservice, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the beginner tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29):

```
def handle_add_two_ints(req):
print "Returning [%s + %s = %s]"%(req.a, req.b, (req.a + req.b))
return AddTwoIntsResponse(req.a + req.b)
```

I understand that the message received will get passed to the 'handle_add_two_ints' function as the object 'req' -- what I do not understand is where the naming convention comes from.  They seem to have pulled '.a' and '.b' out of thin air.  Can someone please clarify or point me to a site that does? What if I am passing many variables of different types... will they always be alphabetically named?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174980/how-do-i-know-the-variable-names-in-a-ros-service-handler/) by [RigorMortis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5128/rigormortis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2014-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

you created a definition of your service interface in a earlier tutorial:

http:// wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv.

Perhaps you didn't realize because you copied it from another project.

```
roscp rospy_tutorials AddTwoInts.srv srv/AddTwoInts.srv
```

The file contains the interface which the function implements.

```
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum
```

hope i helped you

cheers Andreas

---

Originally posted by [andreas.gerken](https://answers.ros.org/users/19000/andreas.gerken/) with karma: 68 on 2014-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RigorMortis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5128/rigormortis/) on 2014-06-25**:
Thanks - that's exactly what I missed!